# Ditto ThingTooLargeException

Tags: eclipse-ditto

I am using ditto and while creating some things I obtain this error **org.eclipse.ditto.things.model.ThingTooLargeException**

I searched on ditto source code and found only this property

**<ditto.limits.things.max-size>102400</ditto.limits.things.max-size>**

on file **ditto\things\model\pom.xml**

I am not very experienced, how can I change this limit?

Answer (score 1):

The default limit of the [Eclipse Ditto](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/) managed [Thing](https://www.eclipse.org/ditto/basic-thing.html) entity is 100k.
This is configured in the [ditto-limits.conf](https://github.com/eclipse/ditto/blob/44a10bea1205eea177e8e48cbb69d0026b10509a/internal/utils/config/src/main/resources/ditto-limits.conf#L15).

You can overwrite this limit by setting the environment variable `LIMITS_THINGS_MAX_SIZE` to something higher, e.g. `LIMITS_THINGS_MAX_SIZE=200k`.
Depending how you start Ditto (e.g. using Kubernetes or Docker Compose) you have to set this environment variable for all Ditto services.

I however want to mention that this limit is there for a reason and that it e.g. does not make sense to configure this much higher.
The stability, throughput, memory consumption, as well as the usage of the database, e.g. regarding search indexes, is influenced by this limit.

So I would rather rethink if a Ditto "Thing" is really the place where you want to store >100k data in.

As a side note: comparable commercial IoT services like AWS IoT Core have a "shadow size limit" (which is the equivalent to the Ditto "thing") of 8k.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I reorganized the data and on the digital twin I no longer store all the data.